# Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'xxx.nupkg' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget, squirrel.windows

I am trying to use squirrel for windows *(version 1.0.0.0)* and there is no way to get rid of that error.

I have done everything to be sure that file is, indeed, not in use.

The following steps reproduce the error on my PC.

1. Create the nuget package to `releasify`
2. Restart the PC
3. Open command prompt only (no other application is running, not even visual studio)
4. Run the command `squirrel --releasify Digger.1.0.0.1.nupkg`

The weird thing is that I am be able to delete the file right after getting the error from the `releasify` command:

The following is the log.

```
2015-08-30 17:28:03> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --releasify Digger.1.0.0.1.nupkg
2015-08-30 17:28:03> Program: Bootstrapper EXE found at:C:\dev\utils\squirrel\Setup.exe
2015-08-30 17:28:03> Program: Creating release package: C:\dev\projects\ThirdParty\inmediati\Digger\Digger.Cliente.WPF\Releases\Digger.1.0.0.1.nupkg
2015-08-30 17:28:03> ReleasePackage: Creating release package: C:\dev\projects\ThirdParty\inmediati\Digger\Digger.Cliente.WPF\Releases\Digger.1.0.0.1.nupkg => C:\dev\projects\ThirdParty\inmediati\Digger\Digger.Cliente.WPF\Releases\Digger-1.0.0.1-full.nupkg
2015-08-30 17:28:03> ReleasePackage: Extracting dependent packages: []
2015-08-30 17:28:03> ReleasePackage: Removing unnecessary data
2015-08-30 17:28:03> ReleasePackage: No release notes found in C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp\tempa\Digger.nuspec
2015-08-30 17:28:03> Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\dev\projects\ThirdParty\inmediati\Digger\Digger.Cliente.WPF\Releases\Digger.1.0.0.1.nupkg' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.Releasify(String package, String targetDir, String packagesDir, String bootstrapperExe, String backgroundGif, String signingOpts, String baseUrl, String setupIcon)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
```

*BTW: The nuget package was created using a `Any CPU` build.*

Comment: Standard bat signal of anti-malware getting in the way.  Make an exclusion and try again.

Comment: Process Monitor will tell you whose dirty fingers are on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're the owner of the thread over on GitHub but just in case anyone else gets the error in the meantime, there appears to be a bug in that particular version of Squirrel, whereby it's not closing a zip file it creates, here is the tracked error : https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/pull/425 doesn't look like too long until it will be fixed.

Here is the link to the other thread in GitHub also : https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/422